# subview not resized with addSubview

Tags: ios, objective-c, resize, addsubview

I have a testViewController which has a subview. Autolayout is turned off. In InterfaceBuilder I have set the Autosizing properties.

[image]

I call this viewController from my MatchViewContoller:

```
-(void)showTutorial
{
    self.testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:self.testViewController.view];
}
```

In the testViewController:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    self.view.backgroundColor=[[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.6];
}
```

The view is shown correctly, but the subview is not resized when I open the view in iPhone 3.5 inch simulator. So now the bottom is not visible.

[image]

I have tried it with `[self.navigationController pushViewController:testViewController animated:NO];` and then it works fine... The subview's subview is resized perfectly. 
[image]

But when I use `[self.view addSubview:self.testViewController.view];` the subview is not resized....

I have tried all combinations with "Autoresize Subviews" turned on and off on the testViewController and the MatchViewController... but nothing works...

What am I missing here? Does resizing not work when you add it with addSubview method?

Comment: I am not sure but try this,       `[self.testViewController.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin];` may it help you

Comment: Try to add [self.view setNeedsLayout] after the adding statement

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you add the view of your testViewController as a subview but you don't add the controller in the viewController hierarchy so life cycle calls like viewDidLoad are not called.

Try this:

```
-(void)showTutorial
{
    self.testViewController = [[TestViewController alloc] init];
    [self addChildViewController:self.testViewController];
    [self.testViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    [self.view addSubview:self.testViewController.view];
}
```

Comment: Nope, that doesn't solve the issue. I also debugged, in my own solution, the ViewDidLoad is called...